# Leer variables PLC con Snap7

Tags: python, plc

Estoy trabajando con la libreria `snap7` en `Python 3.11` para intentar leer las variables de un datablock.

Con este codigo funciona todo bien menos cuando intenta ejecutar la funcion `db_read`, que es donde el programa deja de funcionar.

```
import snap7

IP = '192.168.1.6'
RACK = 0
SLOT = 0

DB_NUMBER = 2
START_ADDRESS = 0
SIZE = 4

plc = snap7.client.Client()
plc.connect(IP,0,1)

plc_info = plc.get_cpu_info()
print(f'Module Type: {plc_info.ModuleTypeName}')

state = plc.get_cpu_state()
print(f'State:{state}')

datablock = plc.db_read(DB_NUMBER, START_ADDRESS, SIZE)

_id = int.from_bytes(datablock[2:4], byteorder='big')
print(f'ID: {_id}')
```

El fallo:

```
File "c:\Users\plc.py", line 20, in <module>
    datablock = plc.db_read(DB_NUMBER, START_ADDRESS, SIZE)
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\snap7\client.py", line 226, in db_read   
    check_error(result, context="client")
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\snap7\common.py", line 89, in check_error
    raise RuntimeError(error)
```

En el Tia Portal 17 tengo activado el PUT/GET y desactivada la optimización del datablock.

El datablock que intento leer tiene dos variables del tipo INT, con un offset total de 4.

Alguna idea de como solucionar el fallo?

Comment: Tal vez ya has intentado esto, pero cuando estaba en esta misma situación, fue porque no desmarqué el acceso de bloque optimizado del DB. De hecho, esto está en las instrucciones originales de Snap7, pero no lo vi: Seleccione el db en el panel izquierdo debajo de "Bloques de programa" y presiona Alt-Enter (o en el menú, selecciona "Propiedades...")
Desmarca el Acceso de bloque optimizado, por defecto te saldrá marcado.

Comment: solo por curiosidad, ¿has intentado lo mismo con `python 3.6? para detectar problemas de incompatibilidad entre versiones.